# Twilio API: Pushing SMS log data to webpage

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-php

I'm working on a project where we need to have a history of incoming text messages dumped to a webpage. I have begun using the Twilio REST API and php library to grab the SMS log data. I'm currently hitting an issue where I'm not able to grab the date sent, however. According to Twilio, I should be able to echo the `DateSent` property. Currently only `body` and `from` are currently working for me.

My php:

```
<?php
// this line loads the library
require('xxxx/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');

$account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

$messages = $client->account->messages->getIterator(0, 50, array(
));

foreach ($messages as $message) {
echo $message->body;
echo $message->DateSent;
echo $message->from;
}
```

Any idea on getting the information I'm seeking to display?

Using js to load this into my webpage and dynamically refresh.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The library actually converts the properties that the API sends into more PHP-like properties. So, instead of using `$message->DateSent` you can use `$message->date_sent`.

Give that a go and let me know if it helps.